# use multiple redis configuration spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, lettuce

i need two redis configuration one for my tokens and one for my invoices
then i need to use them in different middlewares or controllers

here its my InvoiceRedisConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class InvoiceRedisConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.redis.invoice.host:localhost}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${spring.redis.invoice.port:6379}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Bean()
    @Qualifier("invoiceRedisFactory")
    public LettuceConnectionFactory invoiceRedisFactory(){
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(
                new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost,redisPort)
        );
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("invoiceRedisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Invoice> invoiceRedisTemplate(@Qualifier("invoiceRedisFactory") LettuceConnectionFactory invoiceRedisFactory){
        RedisTemplate<String, Invoice> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(invoiceRedisFactory);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class));
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class));
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        return redisTemplate;
    }

}
```

and tokenRedisConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class TokenRedisConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host:localhost}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port:6379}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Bean()
    @Qualifier("tokenRedisFactory")
    public LettuceConnectionFactory tokenRedisFactory(){
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(
                new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost,redisPort)
        );
    }

    @Bean()
    @Qualifier("tokenRedisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String,Token> tokenRedisTemplate(@Qualifier("tokenRedisFactory") LettuceConnectionFactory tokenRedisFactory){
        RedisTemplate<String, Token> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(tokenRedisFactory);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Token.class));
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Token.class));
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        return redisTemplate;
    }




}
```

the problem is when im going to start application it says

```
Parameter 0 of method reactiveRedisTemplate in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisReactiveAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - invoiceRedisFactory: defined by method 'invoiceRedisFactory' in class path resource [tsp/third/party/api/tsp/api/database/connections/invoice/InvoiceRedisConfiguration.class]
    - tokenRedisFactory: defined by method 'tokenRedisFactory' in class path resource [tsp/third/party/api/tsp/api/database/connections/token/TokenRedisConfiguration.class]
```

i don't want to make one of them as my primary i need both in the same time

and i don't have any idea how can i use both

i need to inject tokenRedisTemplate and invoiceRetokenRedisTemplate in my methods without exception

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue of having multiple Redis configurations and injecting the corresponding Redis templates, you can use the **@Qualifier** annotation to specify which Redis template should be injected in each case. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

Update the TokenRedisConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
public class TokenRedisConfiguration {

    // ...

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("tokenRedisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Token> tokenRedisTemplate(
            @Qualifier("tokenRedisFactory") LettuceConnectionFactory tokenRedisFactory
    ) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Token> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(tokenRedisFactory);
        // Configure RedisTemplate
        // ...
        return redisTemplate;
    }

}
```

Update the InvoiceRedisConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
public class InvoiceRedisConfiguration {

    // ...

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("invoiceRedisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Invoice> invoiceRedisTemplate(
            @Qualifier("invoiceRedisFactory") LettuceConnectionFactory invoiceRedisFactory
    ) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Invoice> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(invoiceRedisFactory);
        // Configure RedisTemplate
        // ...
        return redisTemplate;
    }

}
```

In your controller or middleware classes, inject the Redis templates using the @Qualifier annotation:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    private final RedisTemplate<String, Token> tokenRedisTemplate;
    private final RedisTemplate<String, Invoice> invoiceRedisTemplate;

    public MyController(
            @Qualifier("tokenRedisTemplate") RedisTemplate<String, Token> tokenRedisTemplate,
            @Qualifier("invoiceRedisTemplate") RedisTemplate<String, Invoice> invoiceRedisTemplate
    ) {
        this.tokenRedisTemplate = tokenRedisTemplate;
        this.invoiceRedisTemplate = invoiceRedisTemplate;
    }

    // Use tokenRedisTemplate and invoiceRedisTemplate in your methods

}
```

By using the **@Qualifier** annotation along with the respective qualifier names (**tokenRedisTemplate** and **invoiceRedisTemplate**), you can specify which Redis template should be injected in each case. This way, both configurations will coexist, and you'll be able to use the Redis templates without exceptions.

Comment: I'm already using **@Qualifier** annotation on my properties in different class controllers or service classes in order for the function to catch the appropriate class but the problem still exists, I suppose the issue comes up with `eactiveRedisTemplate` function `(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisReactiveAutoConfiguration)`, it sounds as if Spring is running this function but it doesn't know which class should be fired, I'd appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: To resolve this, you can exclude the RedisReactiveAutoConfiguration class from the auto-configuration process by adding it to the @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation in your main application class.

`@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { RedisReactiveAutoConfiguration.class })
public class YourApplication {
    // Your main application code
}`

Comment: By excluding the RedisReactiveAutoConfiguration, you prevent Spring Boot from automatically configuring the reactive Redis template and avoid the conflict between your two Redis configurations.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are using Spring WebFlux and require a reactive Redis template, you can consider using ReactiveRedisTemplate instead of RedisTemplate and modify your configuration classes accordingly. This way, you can have separate reactive Redis configurations for tokens and invoices without conflicts.

Comment: All three of your recent answers here (and even these comments) appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.